# Using function parameters inside anonymous callback returns null/NaN

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, mocha.js

```
getTotalSessions(200);

function getTotalSessions(noToExpect){
    it("Tests some stuff", function(done){
        this.timeout(0);
        setTimeout(function(){
            checkSessions("day", function(total){
                assert.strictEqual(total, noToExpect, "Session number mismatch!\n\nReturned: " + total + "\nExpected: " + noToExpect + "\n");
                done();
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

I'm doing some Mocha tests and I'm getting a weird error in the above code;

`noToExpect` is `NaN` when it comes to asserting, regardless of what number I pass (although above is just an example.

I'm assuming that `noToExpect` is just inside a closure because of the callback used (although I'm new to that concept).

Is there a way I can use the passed parameter inside that closure? Am I just missing something simple?

**Edit:** I added a log of `noToExpect` to the first line inside the `it` and it logged 200, so the number is getting into the `it` correctly.

Comment: I don't supposed the bracket after function(done){ is in the actual code? Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noToExpect` should be available in either of the nested anonymous functions inside of getTotalSessions because of how closures work in Javascript.  I expect that you have some other sort of error that is confusing you into thinking that you don't have access to it.

Some possibilities include:

1. You have some other code error that is changing the execution path from what you think is happening.
2. You have a misspelling in a variable name somewhere.
3. Something other code is changing or redefining or overriding noToExpect.

It sounds like you figured it out, but here's a jsFiddle that shows the general concept you have works if something else isn't goofing it up: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nY6WC/

Comment: I added a log of `noToExpect` to the first line inside the `it` and it logged 200. There are no misspellings, because that is the only interaction between the two.

Comment: Actually, you're right. It was something outside my code playing up.